# Why does passing ClientID to a javascript function pass the whole control?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, internet-explorer-7

If I pass a ClientID to a javascript function as a parameter without including the single quotes around it, it gets passed as a reference to the control itself which can then be used without first calling getElementByID.

I can't find this behaviour documented anywhere, is this a browser specific thing or a .net thing or what?

I am setting up the call like this in code-behind...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button1.Attributes.Add("onClick", string.Format("showvalue({0})",  TextBox1.ClientID));
        }
```

My concern is that this may not work in older versions of IE.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you actually *looked* at the HTML this produces? I don't think that this behavior is all that mysterious as soon as you see the source code.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think it was mysterious I just knew that it is not the way its usually done so was concerned about cross browser support etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add quotes around your ID value when you generate the JS code e.g:
string.Format("showvalue(**'**{0}**'**)",  TextBox1.ClientID)

Without quotes, showValue gets an instance of the global variable with your ClientID name that usually is the DOM element your control rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass it with single quotes and use getElementByID it should work in all browsers, that's the "normal" way.

I'm not sure why this method works as you say. Does it also work in Firefox?